# How to use xpath extractor conditionally in Jmeter?

Tags: xml, testing, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

I have a jmx file in which there is an HTTP request inside which there are XPath Extractors and JSR223 sampler. I want to trigger the XPath Extractors and JSR223 sampler only if the HTTP request is a success.
As whenever the HTTP request fails in can see errors in JMeter command prompt
[image: Sample of How the scripts looks like] [image: The error]

Comment: code and errors as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to execute Post-Processors conditionally, they are always executed after each Sampler in their [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules).

For the JSR223 PostProcessor you can add a clause like:

```
if (prev.isSuccessful()) {
    //your code here
}
```

where `prev` stands for **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands which are available for the JSR223 Test Elements

also be aware that [Groovy has certain XML processing capabilities](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) so you might want to move your extraction logic into the JSR223 PostProcessor.

Comment: I need that XPath extractor. Any ideas on how to write that inside the post-processor i.e JSR223.